# Self referencing an Array of JSON to call a function / to update

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm currently transitioning from VueJS to AlpineJS and trying to update specific JSON arrays but it doesn't seem to be updating.

An example:

Any tips or reasonings why this is not working?

```js
var foo = [

          { id: 0, title: 'test', text: c( this ) },
          { id: 1, title: 'test', text: 'text' },
          { id: 2, title: 'test', text: 'text' },

      ]
function c( idk ) {
    console.log( idk.title )
  }


console.log(foo)
```

```js
var foo = (() => {

  // Paste in your original object
  const foo = [ {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
  }
  ];
  
  // Use their properties
  foo.c = foo.a + foo.b;

  // Do whatever else you want

  // Finally, return object
  return foo;
})();

  console.log( foo )
```

These examples were from [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers) but has been modified to use an Array of JSON

Comment: The **same** reason as the question you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The first example doesn't work for exactly the same reason as the question you referenced.

The second example doesn't work because `foo` is the array and not the object inside the array.

`foo.a + foo.b` is going to be `undefined + undefined` which you then assign to `foo.c` making `foo.c` Not A Number.

You then `console.log` the array and it doesn't show the `c` property because it is an array and not designed to have named properties added to it.

```js
var foo = (() => {
  const foo = [{
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
  }];

  console.log(foo.a, foo.b);

  foo.c = foo.a + foo.b;

  console.log(foo.c);

  return foo;
})();

console.log(foo.c)
```